# Manipular dados retornados de requisição ajax com JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

Minha requisição:

```
 $.post(
      "http://painel.thomerson.com.br/imagens/escolher-template",
      $(this).serialize(),
      function(data){
            $("#Resultado").html(data);
      }
 );
```

O que está acontecendo é que, ao inserir o conteúdo da variável `data` à `div #Resultado`, está sendo inserido o código html completo da própria página, gostaria de saber se há alguma forma de retornar outro tipo de dado.

Tela antes da requisição Ajax:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tela após a requisição Ajax:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Houve duplicação de todo o script :/

Vi alguns exemplos que retornavam dados em `JSON`, trazendo apenas o necessário para manipulação, mas não consegui compreender muito bem como era feito, espero ter sido claro, caso contrário, comentem e eu editarei o que for necessário.

Comment: O que você está querendo obter? `JSON`, `html` ou `xml`? Qual o objetivo desta requisição? Não ficou claro o que você está tentando fazer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você estiver fazendo a mesma requisição da pagina que você está, o ajax quando completar e retornar os dados ele irá retornar todo o conteúdo da mesma tela, fazendo que o conteúdo da sua página de duplique

Comment: Então cara, eu percebi isso, foi esse meu erro, obrigado!